# Migrate static IP from amazon EC2 to Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, amazon-vpc, amazon-lightsail

I am running a server in the Amazon EC2 which has a **static IP** Address, Can we migrate static IP from amazon EC2 **to Lightsail**, Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to migrate the Elastic IP Address from EC2 to Lightsail, because the service and control panel is different. Lightsail is a simplified service with console targeted to people who are familiar with other VPS provider.

Comment: It is not possible currently, but your explanation of why doesn't shed any light on that. It could be built, and it would be of value to those transitioning to EC2. They just don't have the feature right now.